# Why cannot add a large file to a Git repository

Tags: git, git-commit, git-add

Why Git does not support committing very big files? I'm trying to add a 4Gb file and I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\danipen\gitrepos\vmstore>git add mybigfile.rar
fatal: Out of memory? mmap failed: No such file or directory
```

**UPDATE**: Seems that git has a [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6775242/how-can-i-recover-from-fatal-out-of-memory-mmap-failed-cannot-allocate-memor/6812201#6812201) handling [big](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20652850/git-fetch-cannot-allocate-memory) files.

- Do you know any workaround for this issue?
- Maybe should I split the large file in chunks?

Comment: Have you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/a/6812201/220710

Comment: @EmilDavtyan: Thanks for the answer, I'll try. Seems that git has a problem handling big files. I'll update my question.

Comment: Seems this still exists in Git version 1.9.5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should large binary files be in the repository, my opinion is no.

But if you really need version control on binaries or assets consider something like git-fat, or git-lfs

- https://github.com/jedbrown/git-fat
- https://git-lfs.github.com/

Comment: Even git-lfs can't save you.  https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/2434

Answer (score 3):

The idea of Git is to track small files with code. So the suggestion is to include your source files and ignore very big files like static files.

if you include a 4GB file every people who clone the repo have to clone the whole 4GB. Thats not the right way.

Comment: But then there's an unsolved problem here:  how to version control a large (4GB) file.  Back to square one.